# How to calculate the peak-to-peak voltage of a sine wave given RMS voltage

Tags: rf-power, math, voltage

How do I calculate the peak-to-peak voltage of a sine wave given RMS voltage?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### The short answer:

\begin{equation}
\frac{V_{p-p}}{V_{rms}} = 2\sqrt{2}
\end{equation}

#### The long answer, or how to derive the above:

As noted on the Wikipedia page for [root mean square](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_mean_square), the RMS of a sine wave is equal to its amplitude divided by the square root of two. (You can also derive this by doing the integral over a sine wave yourself.)

\begin{equation}
V_{rms} = \frac{a}{\sqrt{2}}
\end{equation}

The peak-to-peak voltage is twice the amplitude of the wave, since it's measuring from the tip of a peak to the tip of a trough.

\begin{equation}
V_{p-p} = 2a
\end{equation}

We can rearrange these two equations:

\begin{equation}
V_{rms} \cdot \sqrt{2} = a
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
V_{p-p} = 2 \cdot (V_{rms} \cdot \sqrt{2})
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
V_{p-p} = V_{rms} \cdot 2\sqrt{2}
\end{equation}

Thus, we multiply the RMS voltage by twice the square root of two - a factor of about 2.828 or so:

\begin{equation}
2\sqrt{2} = 2.8284271247....
\end{equation}

Of course, the process also works in reverse - if you can measure the peak-to-peak voltage, dividing that by the same factor will give you the RMS voltage assuming a perfect sine wave.

Comment: I hope we get LaTeX equation support here - this would be a great use case for it!

Comment: @Dan yep, hoping it gets turned on soon.

Comment: Can you explain a little more? I'm still not entirely following.

Answer (score 0):

In a pure sine wave $V_{RMS} \times 1.414$ will give you peak. $V_{Peak} \times .707$ will give you RMS.

Comment: Note, however, that "peak" and "peak to peak" are not the same thing.

Comment: That formula will work for "peak "or "peak to peak" depending on what you feed it. Of course peak × 2 also works for" p to p.